# Question About SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the below statement to generate age of a person in Oracle SQL and my question is below.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY'))-TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(BIRTH_DATE,'YYYY')) 
FROM NAME WHERE NAME_ID =NAME_ID
```

This statement is only correct upto so far that I need a statement which could count months and even days in order to get the age.

Comment: There is a similar question, albeit on MSSQL. Maybe it can help you get started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283764/finding-someones-age-in-sql

Comment: Could someone please help me convert the above linked statement to Oracle SQL. I am a dummy at Oracle SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Googling for 'oracle get age from dob' returns several answers

```
select trunc((months_between(sysdate, dob))/12) age
from name;
```

looks like a good solution (trunc is optional) and

```
select to_number(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY')) - to_number(to_char(bth_date,'YYYY'))  +
       decode(sign(to_number(to_char(sysdate,'MMDD')) - 
                   to_number(to_char(bth_date,'MMDD'))),-1,-1,0) age
from name;
```

is also correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [EXTRACT function](http://download-uk.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions052.htm) like

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM( CURRENT_DATE - BIRTH_DATE )) FROM ...
```

Substitute YEAR by whatever you need.

/edit I think I misread. If you need higher precisions maybe Intervals could help (http://blagispat.blogspot.com/2007/11/heres-short-article-on-using-intervals.html). (Sry but new users can only post one hyperlink).

```
SELECT EXTRACT( YEAR FROM( CURRENT_DATE - BIRTH_DATE) YEAR TO MONTH ) FROM ...
```

or

```
SELECT EXTRACT( DAY FROM( CURRENT_DATE - BIRTH_DATE) DAY TO SECOND ) FROM ...
```

which returns days.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports arithmetic operations directly on `DATE` columns:

```
SELECT SYSDATE - BIRTH_DATE FROM NAME WHERE NAME_ID =NAME_ID
```

The result here will be a number which expresses the difference in days.

If you want it in months, use this:

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, BIRTH_DATE) FROM NAME...
```

If you want it in years, divide `MONTHS_BETWEEN` by 12.