# DateDiff Missing few records

Tags: t-sql, datediff

I am using the datediff function

```
SELECT stName
       ,stId
       ,stDob  --(varchar(15))
       ,stJoinDt --(datetime)
FROM student stu
WHERE
DATEDIFF(yy,stu.stDob,stu.stJoinDt) between 18 and 75
```

Since the between operator is not effective I have also changed the code to

```
SELECT stName
           ,stId
           ,stDob
           ,stJoinDt
    FROM student stu
    WHERE
    DATEDIFF(yy,stu.stDob,stu.stJoinDt) >= 18 
    AND  DATEDIFF(yy,stu.stDob,stu.stJoinDt) < 75
```

Is there any other effective way to write datediff to capture all the missing records?

```
The missing records are
stDob             stJoinDt
10/08/1925        2011-01-03
04/18/1935        2011-01-19
12/11/1928        2011-06-06
1/24/1927         2011-04-18
04/18/1918        2011-04-20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those records *should* be missing because the number of years between stDob and stJoinDt is *not* between 18 and 75, as you are filtering them out with your condition that stDob and stJoinDt differ by between 18 and 75 years:

```
with student as (
    select 'Bob' as stName, 1 as stId, '10/08/1925' as stDob,        '2011-01-03' as stJoinDt
    union select 'Bob' as stName, 2 as stId, '04/18/1935',        '2011-01-19'
    union select 'Bob' as stName, 3 as stId, '12/11/1928',        '2011-06-06'
    union select 'Bob' as stName, 4 as stId, '1/24/1927 ',        '2011-04-18'
    union select 'Bob' as stName, 5 as stId, '04/18/1918',        '2011-04-20'
)
    SELECT stName
           ,stId
           ,stDob  --(varchar(15))
           ,stJoinDt --(datetime)
           ,datediff(yy, stu.stDob, stu.stJoinDt) as DiffYears
    FROM student stu
```

Output:

```
stName  stId    stDob           stJoinDt    DiffYears
Bob     1       10/08/1925      2011-01-03  *86* (>75)
Bob     2       04/18/1935      2011-01-19  *76* (>75)
Bob     3       12/11/1928      2011-06-06  *83* (>75)
Bob     4       1/24/1927       2011-04-18  *84* (>75)
Bob     5       04/18/1918      2011-04-20  *93* (>75)
```

My guess would be you were wanting to capture all records where the person is at least 18 years old.  In that case, remove the 75 part from the filter:

```
WHERE
DATEDIFF(yy,stu.stDob,stu.stJoinDt) >= 18 
-- STOP HERE
```

Although technically this does not perform the correct calculation, because it is only finding the difference in the year values and not taking into account day and month.  For instance, a date-of-birth of 12/31/1990 and a join date of 1/1/2008 would register as 18 years even though the person is only 17 years, 1 day old.  I would recommend instead using the solution provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283764/finding-someones-age-in-sql):

```
where
    (DATEDIFF(YY, stu.stDob, stu.stJoinDt) -
        CASE WHEN( 
            (MONTH(stDob)*100 + DAY(stDob)) > (MONTH(stJoinDt)*100 + DAY(stJoinDt))
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    ) >= 18
```