# How to find most recent birthday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Table1

```
ID Dateofbirth

001 01/01/1988 'dd/mm/yyyy
002 01/05/2001
....
```

From the table1, i want to find the most recent birthday of each id. Most recent birthday should validate with system date.

Expected output

```
ID Dateofbirth MostRecentBirthday

001 01/01/1988  01/01/2012
002 01/05/2001  01/05/2011 
....
```

ouput explanation

```
For 001, most recent birthday is 01/01/2012
For 002, most recent birthday is 01/05/2011 ' because still we are not reached this date 01/05/2012
```

Comment: is the column data type DateTime or VARCHAR?

Comment: what about leap-day? how do you want to handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the answer to the previous question:

```
select ID,
       Dateofbirth,
       dateadd(yy,
               datediff(yy,Dateofbirth,getdate()) -
                           case when dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,Dateofbirth,getdate()),Dateofbirth)>getdate()
                           then 1 else 0 end,
               Dateofbirth) MostRecentBirthday
from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column type is `DATE` (or `DATETIME`):

```
SELECT id,
       Dateofbirth,
       CONVERT(date,
         DATEPART(month, Dateofbirth) + '/'
       + DATEPART(day, Dateofbirth) + '/'
       + CASE WHEN DATEPART(month, Dateofbirth) < DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) OR 
                   (DATEPART(month, Dateofbirth) = DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) AND DATEPART(day, Dateofbirth) < DATEPART(day, GETDATE()))
              THEN DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
              ELSE DATEPART(year, GETDATE())-1
         END,
       101) AS MostRecentBirthday
FROM your_table
```

Not tested, but should be pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an [Age UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9085213/251034), then the query can simply be:

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Dateofbirth,
  DATEADD(year, dbo.Age(Dateofbirth), Dateofbirth) AS MostRecentBirthday
FROM
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This idea may help

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  dateofbirth, 
  convert(nvarchar(10), day(dateofbirth)) + "/" + 
  convert(nvarchar(10), month(dateofbirth)) + 
  CASE month(getdate()) > Month(dateofbirth) 
  WHEN TRUE THEN convert(nvarchar(10), year(getdate())) 
          ELSE CASE month(getdate()) < Month(dateofbirth) 
               WHEN TRUE THEN convert(nvarchar(10), Year(getdate())-1) 
                         ELSE CASE day(getdate()) >= day(dateofbirth) 
                                    WHEN TRUE THEN Year(getdate()) 
                                    ELSE Year(getdate())-1) 
                                    END 
                         END 
          END MostRecentBirthday
FROM .....
```